# Any way of running instagram in linux

Tags: instagram

So I've searched through every possible tutorial I could find (archon, arc welder, chromeos-apk, genymotion, anbox, shashlik) and I'm pretty sure i've gotten the programs themselves to work (correct me if there is a way on any of these), it's just none of them seem to be able to run android instagram. Any suggestions? I want something I can post and send direct messages with.

Comment: Any reason you dont want to use the API?

Comment: Probably not the best solution, but you could run Android-x86 under virtualbox to run the Instagram app. It'll take some time to boot up though

Answer (score 1):

Search for `Instagraph` in Software Center or download and install it using [this link](https://github.com/turanmahmudov/Instagraph); It may fit your requirements.

The installation process is quite easy:

Install software by:

```
snap install instagraph
```

and grant access to camera, audio and etc.:

```
snap connect instagraph:camera :camera
snap connect instagraph:alsa :alsa
snap connect instagraph:pulseaudio :pulseaudio
snap connect instagraph:opengl :opengl
```

**Update:**

`Ramme` is another tool you can use as a Linux-based Instagram client ([Link](https://github.com/terkelg/ramme/)). It also works in Windows and MacOS